# Python can't open file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется Python 3.7.2
Пытаюсь открыть скрипт через консоль, в скрипте просто тестовый `print`.
Скрипт называет `www.py`, лежит в `D:\pythonw`
Перехожу в директорию с помощью `cd D:\pythonw`
И вроде как должно всё работать.
Но получаю ошибку:

```
python: can't open file 'www.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Так вот, как сделать чтобы Python увидел мой скрипт?

Comment: а команда `echo %cd%` что показывает? или команда `dir`

Comment: Показывают начальную директорию папки командной строки С:\User\User, будто я и не переходил в нужную мне папку

Comment: напишите `D:`, чтобы сменить локальный диск

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало, а можете дать ссылку где почитать про работу с командной строкой, а то я вот только сел за её освоение)

Comment: имхо, в винде командная строка не очень удобная.. а может я просто не умею ее готовить. В linux, как по мне, поприятнее будет. На [stepic.org](https://stepik.org) есть хорошие курсы по линуксу (вместе с командами в терминале)

Comment: "_Показывают начальную директорию папки командной строки С:\User\User, будто я и не переходил в нужную мне папку_" - в следующий раз смотри на то, выполнилась ли команда, ДО того, как запустить следующую.

Comment: Спасибо ребят еще раз, сайт годный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` - change **directory**. Меняет папку, а не диск. Чтобы перейти на другой диск нужно использовать `cd` с флагом `/d`:

```
cd /d d:
```

Или просто сразу ввести

```
D:
```